# Make a Company Website Useable as a Kiosk with an overlay Navigation

Tags: android, overlay, kiosk-mode

I would like to use our company-website in a custom Kiosk mode with some overlayed buttons in a live event setting on Tablets.

f.ex.

- Some kind of entry page with buttons as a navigation (direct links to all the departments)
- Contact us (linked Form to get in touch with our sales team)
- Thematic Navigation (to get to the different study areas)
- a way to get back to the navigation in one klick

The goal-sites already exist. Imo it would be enough to Load the Website and use an seperate Navigation on top of that. Is there any possibility to achieve that with really little programming knwowledge?

I had a look at existing opportunities in Chrome or other mobile browser. There is the possibility for Kiosk mode but the navigation of the website itself is not intuitive enough for live events and i can't put any overlay on it